# Universal Search - Redirect to Custom screen

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom screen which is a duplicate of the Customer screen. The question is, when we enter customer id in universal search, how we can redirect to our custom screen instead of the Customer screen. Please have a look at the graph code of our custom screen.

```
public class CustomScreen : BusinessAccountGraphBase<Customer, Customer, Where<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
                Or<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>
    {
    }
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating the customer screen and not customizing it?

Comment: That is user requirement and this duplicate customer screen is just view purpose to view all transaction data will see in this duplicate customer screen

Answer (score 1):

The Search box is using the value of the Note ID field of the records as the key for finding the record in the `SearchIndex` where the `EntityType` is stored for the record.
From the `EntityType` it is reading the value of the `PXPrimaryGraphAttribute` and doing the redirect to the specified graph.

To change the page where the redirect will go you need to change the value of the `PXPrimaryGraphAttribute` of that DAC.

You can try adding the `PXPrimaryGraphAttribute` to your graph to indicate that it is the primary graph for the specified DAC. Per documentation, it is supposed to override the primary graph set by the `PXPrimaryGraphAttribute` applied to the `Customer` DAC.

In case of `Customer` DAC the applied attribute is the following:

```
[CRCacheIndependentPrimaryGraphList(new Type[]
{
    typeof(BusinessAccountMaint),
    typeof(CustomerMaint),
    typeof(CustomerMaint),
    typeof(CustomerMaint),
    typeof(BusinessAccountMaint)
}, new Type[]
{
    typeof(Select<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, And<Current<BAccount.viewInCrm>, Equal<True>>>>),
    typeof(Select<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, Or<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccountR.bAccountID>>>>>),
    typeof(Select<Customer, Where<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Current<BAccount.acctCD>>, Or<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Current<BAccountR.acctCD>>>>>),
    typeof(Where<BAccountR.bAccountID, Less<Zero>, And<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>>>),
    typeof(Select<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, Or<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>, Less<Zero>>>>)
})]
```

As you can see depending on the specified conditions the DAC can be assigned to either `BusinessAccountMaint` or `CustomerMaint` and you need to change the conditions and graphs correspondingly to what you need.

For example like below:

```
[CRCacheIndependentPrimaryGraphList(new Type[]
{
    typeof(BusinessAccountMaint),
    typeof(CustomScreen),
    typeof(CustomScreen),
    typeof(CustomScreen),
    typeof(BusinessAccountMaint)
}, new Type[]
{
    typeof(Select<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, And<Current<BAccount.viewInCrm>, Equal<True>>>>),
    typeof(Select<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, Or<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccountR.bAccountID>>>>>),
    typeof(Select<Customer, Where<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Current<BAccount.acctCD>>, Or<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Current<BAccountR.acctCD>>>>>),
    typeof(Where<BAccountR.bAccountID, Less<Zero>, And<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>>>),
    typeof(Select<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, Or<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>, Less<Zero>>>>)
})]
public class CustomScreen : BusinessAccountGraphBase<Customer, Customer, Where<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
            Or<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>
{
}
```

Comment: Hi Samvel, I tried the given solution by adding above my custom graph and rebuilt index in SM209500 even after that when i search customer it is redirecting to customer screen only not to my custom screen, also i didn't create customer extension DAC.
Updated code above please refer and let me know the issue please.

Comment: Here is the modified code after the answer

`
 [CRCacheIndependentPrimaryGraphList(new Type[]
{
typeof(BusinessAccountMaint),
 typeof(CustomerDupMaint),
 typeof(CustomerDupMaint),
typeof(CustomerDupMaint), 
typeof(BusinessAccountMaint)
}, 
new Type[]{
    typeof(Select<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, And<Current<BAccount.viewInCrm>, Equal<True>>>>),
 typeof(Select<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, Or<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccountR.bAccountID>>>>>),
`

Comment: typeof(Select<Customer, Where<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Current<BAccount.acctCD>>, Or<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Current<BAccountR.acctCD>>>>>), 
typeof(Where<BAccountR.bAccountID, Less<Zero>, And<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>>>), typeof(Select<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, Or<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>, Less<Zero>>>>)})]

    public class CustomerDupMaint : BusinessAccountGraphBase<Customer, Customer, Where<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
 Or<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>
    {    }